# how to display in a left menu the child items of main menu

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I want to build a site with two menus. The first menu will be in the top pane and the second menu will be in the left pane.

What I am looking for is how to show the child items in the left pane.

For example, for a page with name "testPage" where it has as child menu items "testPageChild1" and "testPageChild2", I want in the left pane to display those child items.

How could I do this?

If there is another way to implement something like this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with your menu, or you can do it with a module as notandy points out. The "console" module is also an option, it will provide links to children of whatever page lyou point to.

As for doing it within the skin, using the Menu, you need to adjust the "Level" attribute of the Navigation control.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="NAV" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Nav.ascx" %>
<dnn:NAV id="TopLevel" runat="server" Level="Root" />
<dnn:NAV id="Child" runat="server" Level="Child" />
```

and then style accordingly

Comment: This really is a best practice way to approach this.

Comment: Chris, do you think it's possible to do with DDR Treeview menu as well? I'm trying to hide the root level and just showing sub and its child..

Comment: @nana it might be possible but I really haven't worked with DDR menu all that much

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a child links module. You simply add it to the left pane and then configure it to show subpages of the current page.
I usually use Ventrian's http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/ChildLinks.aspx.
But there are a number of others available, including a free one http://dnnmodules.cn/Modules/Childpagelistfree.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

according to http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-user-guide

i've tried to set my module to `NodeSelector="RootChildren"` and i worked.

Comment: While we appreciate your interest in answering this question, it is almost 5 years old, and already has an accepted answer. Your efforts might be better spent answering a more recent one.

Comment: i was struggling in this so i thought it may be useful to add another answer though